# Arrange dataframe header after pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have done a pivot and my new dataframe looks like this:

[image]

Thus the `userId` column is now an index and I have a 2-level header. How can I go to a single level header that looks like:

```
' ' , 'userId' , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

where the empty entry is the index of the dataframe, and userId is a regular column?

Comment: kindly share data, not pics, for both input and output dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stack` method of dataframe to convert the column of level 1 to the index, then use `reset_index` to convert index to columns:

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                           

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(3), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2], ['a', 'b']])).fillna(1)                                         

In [4]: df = df.stack(level=-1)                                                                                                                       

In [5]: df                                                                                                                                            
Out[5]: 
     1  2
0 a  1  1
  b  1  1
1 a  1  1
  b  1  1
2 a  1  1
  b  1  1

In [6]: df = df.reset_index(drop=False).set_index('level_0')                                                                                          

In [7]: df                                                                                                                                            
Out[7]: 
        level_1  1  2
level_0              
0             a  1  1
0             b  1  1
1             a  1  1
1             b  1  1
2             a  1  1
2             b  1  1
```

Comment: Hi, I made an edit, sorry for not being clear. I want userId to be a simple column and the index column to be unnamed, as usual.

Comment: then you can `unstack` the dataframe first, then convert the last level of the index to a column, see the modified answer.